# WebClient returning: response if no proxy given

Tags: c#, proxy, webclient, fiddler

I want to upload a file with WebClient.UploadFile and is as

```
string proxyserver = "http://10.0.0.127:8080/";
IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyserver);
proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
WebClient Client = new WebClient();

Client.Headers.Add("UA-CPU", "x86");
Client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us");
Client.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
Client.Proxy = proxy;
byte[] rawResponse = Client.UploadFile(uri, filename);
string response = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawResponse);
```

I am getting remote server returned an error 403 Forbidden and if i comment the proxy i am able to get response, but i can't see response in fiddler, not knowing why? and also  how can i work this with proxy

Comment: if i set like this WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(); proxy.GetProxy(proxyserver); i am getting address null but going through proxy don't know whether it is hitting proxy or not

Comment: Fiddler *is* a proxy server. If you tell your code to use a different proxy, Fiddler will not see that traffic. Are you sure your proxy server is up?